# Possible Concurrency issues in using reflection in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.reflection

I have a requirement where based on the Class Name passed as string from a Third party application, I want to get all properties and its value and assign their values to another object having members with similar names. Now I know this can be done without any issue in a Win Form application but I want to know what all issues will be there if I use this approach in an ASP.NET application - I am not much concerned with the Performance but specifically with the Concurrency (if any possible)

I am using code something like as below:

```
//Just a Sample Code 
Type type = Type.GetType("MyClassName");
var propValue = type.GetProperty("MyProperyName").GetValue(myObject);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency Issues like Race condition etc will come into picture if you are writing or making changes to the values, here you only reading properties, which are already added to metadata of type (Type definition, property definition) tables when you compile your code.

And there is no way you can alter that definition at runtime as long as I know, so the things you are doing is thread safe as long as your type and propvalues are local to thread executing.